# How do I print a shape in a loop?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I am trying to print shapes in a loop, but when I run the program nothing shows up. I am using shapes from a custom class I made earlier. I use mouse clicks to get each end of the mouse (in a different section) and that is working.

```
@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i<howMany;i++){
        if (shapes[i] instanceof Line){ 
            Line l = (Line) shapes[i];
            g.drawLine((int)l.start.getX(),(int) l.start.getY(),(int) l.end.getX(),(int) l.end.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the shapes of type line?

Comment: *but when I run the program nothing shows up* - 1) how do you know the Array contains any lines? 2) did you add the panel to the frame? 3) did you override the getPreferredSize() to give the panel a size? See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a complete working example.

Comment: Without more details (what is the size of the component? what is the current color & stroke? how many lines are being passed in?) this question cannot be really answered. Can you post a complete, minimal program that reproduces the issue?

Comment: thanks guys. sorry if this is dumb haha i am just starting to code and a bit confused. fixed it now!

Comment: *fixed it now!* - how? If people read this they will want to knw how it was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove repaint request and double check that `shapes` is not empty and `shapes[i]` is actually a `Line`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i<howMany;i++){
        if (shapes[i] instanceof Line){ 
            Line l = (Line) shapes[i];
            g.drawLine((int)l.start.getX(),(int) l.start.getY(),(int) l.end.getX(),(int) l.end.getY());
           // repaint(); remove that 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the repaint() should definitely not be there, if will not prevent the component from painting itself. It will just continually paint itself increasing CPU usage and potentially reduce responsiveness of the code since it is in a continuous cycle to paint itself.

Comment: calling `repaint()` marks the component as dirty, so that it will be repainted on the next update. Calling it many times in a row has the same effect as calling it just once. Yes, it is redundant (and will result in constant updates as long as the application runs) - but it will continue to sort-of-work.